# Could you recommend action recognition dataset?

Tags: datasets, action-recognition

**background**

I want to do action recognition for academic, but I can't find dataset what I want.

so, I wonder Which dataset is suitable for me...

**What I want?**
I want to find dataset such as..

1. ***labeling with joint point***. [example image](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341097929/figure/fig2/AS:886569468719110@1588386041504/The-label-of-each-joint-points.jpg).
   If labeling more detail, such as " joint point + eye point + ear point + etc" is okay.
2. ***many categories with clearly defined actions.***
   I see some datasets, but they grouped poses with big categories. For example, Jumping category. They grouped jumping with jumping with one leg, jumping with two leg, jumping along in a squatting position ... etc. These are jumping, but These are not actually same pose. Another examples are eating. eating hamburger, eating with forks, eating with spoon, eating with chopsticks are really different but similar actions. also, these are not good for classification.
3. ***similar frames per recording actions.(not necessary condition)***
   Some datasets are not same frames per poses. For example, running is 520 frame, walking is 300 frames. These numbers just for explain, not real frames. I hope frame numbers are similar each others, but I knew that it is difficult to unify the number of frames. So, this is not necessary condition.
4. ***Many recordings per each category.(not necessary condition, but I really want to find it)***
   I want to find many recordings per each category, but recordings are not various. When I open some dataset, each categories are about 20~50 recordings. BUT I need more categories over 500 recordings for each training, test data.
   Few category(about 10 category) available is okay, but many recordings are necessary to me. I knew that it is difficult to make many recordings. So, this is not necessary condition.
5. ***free or less constraints dataset access***
   If dataset has contraints such as needed sign up or for use local residents, It can hard to access anyone. I want to share my experiment when my experiment get good results. But if dataset access are limited, then It can hard to share my experiments.

**What I found?**

1. [human3.6m dataset](http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/description.php). However, It takes very long time to get account. I wait for over 1 month, but any contacts came to me.
2. some limited dataset. It has many constraints(such as only use local residents, only use members, etc), so it doesn't help to me.

I will update the lists when someone recommend dataset to me. Thank you.